# Google Maps, how to open & close multiple infoboxes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

the following code which is mainly lifted from the Google tutorial and changed infowindows to infoboxes works like this.

1. Loads & Opens all infoboxes correctly.
2. Closes infoboxes when clicked on close icon.
3. Will not Open any infobox when clicking marker, except the last marker added to the map *(which is the last in the array if that helps)*.

I've tried several options but am having no luck getting the infobox to open again, except for the last added marker, please help me.

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    scrollwheel: false
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() { ib.close() });

  var ib = new InfoBox();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {

    var xml = data.responseXML;

    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");

      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point
      });

      bounds.extend(marker.position);

      var boxText = document.createElement("div");
      boxText.innerHTML = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/><div id='station_data'><h2>Station Down</h2></div>";;

      var myOptions = {
         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: { 
          width: "280px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "-10px -10px 0px 0px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "close_icon.png"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
      };

        var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        ib.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            ib.open(map, marker);
        });

    }

       map.fitBounds(bounds);



  });
}


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
```

Comment: The duplicate example solves your issue (associating the marker with the infowindow) with function closure.

Comment: Yeah I figured out I needed to bind it, should I delete this question?

Comment: You don't need to, it might lead someone else to the answer.